# Hide/show (disable/enable) a sheet via macros qlickview

Tags: vbscript, macros, action, business-intelligence, qlikview

I try to explain as best as possible

I need to hide a few sheets via vbscript macro, so that when i print the document they are not visible. i can retrieve a sheet via its id and then hide/show it?

example:

function Hide

```
    Dim strValueToDisplay 

    strValue = split(ActiveDocument.Variables("vHideSheetList").GetContent().String,",")

    for each sheetId in strValue
        'msgbox(sheetId)
        ActiveDocument.Sheets(sheetId).Hide
    next
```

function Show

```
    Dim strValueToDisplay 

    strValue = split(ActiveDocument.Variables("vHideSheetList").GetContent().String,",")

    for each sheetId in strValue
        'msgbox(sheetId)
        ActiveDocument.Sheets(sheetId).Show
    next
```

thx!

Comment: I think you want `Visible` boolean property to do this `ActiveDocument.Sheets(sheetId).Visible = True` or `False` respectively.

Comment: Using 'ActiveDocument.Sheets (...). Visible' I get the following error: "Property or method not supported by the object: 'ActiveDocument.Sheets (...). Visible'"

Comment: In that case, it's not the Excel Object Model, sorry my mistake. for more information see [Worksheet.Visible Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx).

Comment: I'm working with QlikView and not with Excel